# Unknown when I receive incoming calls on Iphone 5S

Tags: iphone

I have an Iphone 5S. When I receive calls I do not see a number it only reflects "Unknown" on the screen. How can I change this to ensure that it reflects either the number or name if the person is in my address book?

Comment: If it is not in your contacts you will see the Unknown message.

Comment: If the caller is not in your contacts, you'll see the phone number of the caller. You'll see "Unknown" if the caller suppressed the number.

Answer (score 4):

If you see "Unknown" this means that the caller is not transmitting his ID (i.e. number) to your carrier and hence your iPhone.

Not much can be changed unless you pick up the phone and ask the caller to change his Caller ID settings on his phone.

In addition, some business numbers and calls over VoIP tend to appear as "Unknown". It is not the fault of your iPhone but from where exactly the call originates.

Comment: For many US carriers transmitting the Caller ID portion of the incoming ring packet is a paid option on your cellular service. AT&T, for example, charges extra to see the phone numbers of incoming callers. Without that option on your cellular plan you will always see `Unknown` as the carrier blocks this information.

Comment: There are no wireless carriers that I know of in the US which charge additional for caller id.  AT&T does not charge extra for its wireless plans.  It is very common to charge extra for caller id on landline phones, but the iPhone is not a landline.

Comment: Indeed, I agree. I don't know of any US carrier who would charge you for showing your cell number ID.

Answer (score 1):

If this goes for all contacts, check your settings:
settings > phone > callerID > on

If its just for 1 contact:
I'm really sorry, but as far as I know, it's not possible to get any names or phone number shown as they're not transmitting it.